# sending array of objects to MVC4 controller with $http or $.ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

Apparently I am doing something wrong, Tried everything.

Initially I needed to send array of objects to asp.net mvc controller using angular's $http, well it didn't work.

Then I tried to use jquery. I've tried `$.get`, `$.post`, `$.ajax` methods with different parameters (traditional, non-traditional, with `dataType:'json'`, without it - still can't pass the values. This thing is killing me.

```
$.ajax(
  url: '/Home/Foo'
  data: items: [{'name':'some'},{'name':'other'}])

public JsonResult Foo(Item[] items)
{
    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public class Item
{
   public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The best what I could get out of it - it recognizes items as Item[] array but every `name` value is null

Comment: `data: items: [{'name':'some'},{'name':'other'}]` is incorrect JSON syntax. Try `data: { 'items' : [{'name':'some'},{'name':'other'}]}` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this article

http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/

it should be a string:

```
$.ajax(
   url: '/Home/Foo'
   data: "{ 'items': [{'name':'some'},{'name':'other'}] }"
```

Now using JSON.stringify should solve my problem. Still gotta try using $http

Comment: I think that the article you've linked to refers to an `ASMX` service operation, not an MVC4 HTTP service operation. I've used raw JSON data (i.e. not a string) against MVC4; it should work OK.

Answer (score 1):

When passing a JSON string to MVC, be sure to set a Content-Type of `application/json`. Otherwise, MVC will expect the data in URLEncoded format instead of JSON.

JSON typically does work best for passing in arrays though, so you should be on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` string (i.e. `data: items: [{'name':'some'},{'name':'other'}]`) is invalid JSON syntax, while your stringified JSON string in your self-answer is of correct syntax.

You shouldn't have to convert your object into a JSON string, and a standard Javascript object should work.

Try switching that to:

```
$.ajax(
    url: '/Home/Foo',
    data: { 
        'items': [{'name':'some'},{'name':'other'}]
    }
)
```